# Can we add Menu Items in the GameObject menu that doesn't display in the context menu of the hierarchy window?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, menuitem

I want to create my own Menu Item that behaves like the "Create Empty Child" unity default method.

this method displays in the GameObject menu like this :
[GameObject Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4T9E.png)
but doesn't displays in the context menu (with the right click) in the hierarchy window :
[Hierarchy Context Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pa83T.png)

Comment: I don't think this is possible but you need to add the current Menu code you have to your question

Comment: I finally found how to do it :
I have to not precise the priority level and it works (in Unity 2017.1 at least), that's strange the last time I tested I don't remember it was reacting like this (maybe I tested that on an older unity version))

To resume : I finally succeed by doing this :
[MenuItem ("GameObject/MyButton", false)]
instead of this :
[MenuItem ("GameObject/MyButton", false, -1)]

Comment: Post this as answer to your question

Comment: I know now why it was not working before, the method should be at the root of the GameObject menu :

with [MenuItem ("GameObject/MyButton", false)] : MyButton does not appear in hierarchy context menu

with [MenuItem ("GameObject/SomeSubCategory/MyButton", false)]  : MyButton appears in hierarchy context menu

that's no logical at all, but now I know how it works

Comment: Like I said before, post that as answer instead of comment. It will help many people in the future.

Comment: Sorry I think when you are low in reputation there is a delay before you can answer your own question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found how to do that :
It works when you do not precise the priority level and the method is at the root of the GameObject menu. I know, it's weird.

For example : `[MenuItem ("GameObject/MyButton", false)]` works
but `[MenuItem ("GameObject/MyButton", false, -1)]` or `[MenuItem ("GameObject/Subfolder/MyButton", false)]` doesn't work.